# pip module they disappear after reboot

Tags: python, home-assistant

I don't understand why (home assistant on `raspberry pi 4`), after installing modules with pip, when the `server` is `restarted` they `disappear`..

before reboot
[image: install before reboot]

after reboot

[image: after reboot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Is the Pi booted as a live session or something? That is, how did you install the OS on it? For that matter, what OS are you using?

Comment: @wjandrea thanks for reply, I installed the OS via the Raspberry app, it's not live also because everything I do is normally saved. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you updated pip version? Are you using Bullseye or Bookworm?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to install the packages using

```
python3 -m pip install <package_name>
```

You can also try using `pip3` if the former doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the result is error externally-managed-environment